# Firebase JobDispatcher-Scheduled jobs are lost on device reboot

Tags: android, firebase, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am using [Firebase-JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android).I have scheduled some jobs and its working fine if i keep the device switch on.But if i reboot my device then  the scheduled jobs doesn't execute or it doesn't get rescheduled?I have used `setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)`.Still jobs are lost on device reboot.Below is the code i m using-

```
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
.setService(MyJobService.class)
.setTag("DataSend")
.setRecurring(false)
.setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0))
.setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
.setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
.setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
.build();
```

Comment: There is an issue - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/101

Answer (score 3):

After setting `Lifetime.FOREVER` you have add the following permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

And below is the code to schedule a job

```
Job job = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(windowStartTime, 3600))
    .setTag(PENDING_AUTH_JOB) //identifier for the job
    .setRecurring(false) // should not recur
    .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER) // should persist device reboot
    .setReplaceCurrent(false) // no need to replace previous job
    .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK) // set network availability constraint
    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
    .build();
try {
  jobDispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
} catch (FirebaseJobDispatcher.ScheduleFailedException e) {
  if (retryCount-- > 0) {
    scheduleJob(0);
  }
}
```

One more thing to check is not set execution window to `0,0`. always set a  `windowEnd` greater that `windowStart`

Comment: Are the constraints met after reboot? I mean is the phone connected to internet to run the job?

Comment: yes it is connected to internet and if i schedule new job that job executes.only if i reboot device jobs are lost

Comment: I am testing by disconnecting internet while scheduling jobs and reconnecting to internet after device reboot

Comment: Can you post the jobservice code. Just to know how you are deciding whether job is executed or not

Comment: I have put a log statement at beginning of onStartJob to check whether its called or not .Also i am sending images to server inside my job service and on basis of these things i can know that my job is executed or not

Comment: i have added my code to schedule the job. it works fine for me even after a reboot. i had the same problem of job not rescheduling after reboot. just adding that permission made it to work.

Comment: what intent filters are u using for service?

Comment: Im not using any intentfilters

Comment: but in github documentation its written we have to use `<action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>`

Comment: If i increase `Trigger.executionWindow(0,0)` to `Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60)` than it works fine and job gets executed after reboot when network connection is there.So `Lifetime.FOREVER` doesn't work if the execution window end is less or small.i.e.around Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0) to Trigger.executionWindow(0, 15).Please test and update answer before i can accept your answer.

Comment: yes, setting `Trigger.executionWindow(0,0)` is the problem here. I have edited the answer

Comment: Try with `Trigger.executionWindow(0, 5) ..it will also not execute the job after reboot.As per my understanding,the problem is not that windowEnd and windowStart is same..I think Lifetime.FOREVER doesn't work if the execution window end is less or small..Trigger.executionWindow(0, 0) is used to start the job immediately if all constraints are met

Comment: I have set this .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12)).intValue(), Long.valueOf(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(12)).intValue() + 60)). I turned off the phone and after 15 hours I turned on, then job is not running. Do you know what happens in this scenario? I haven't found a solution or answer yet. I tried to change the system time and doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your MyJobService should return false so that the job can be rescheduled after executing;

```
  public boolean onStartJob(final com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobParameters jobParameters) {

        //Offloading work to a new thread.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                codeYouWantToRun(jobParameters);
            }
        }).start();

        return true;
    }



 public void codeYouWantToRun(final JobParameters parameters) {
 Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobStarted");
//bla bla super code doing its linga linga ling 
                Log.d(TAG, "completeJob: " + "jobFinished");

                    //Tell the framework that the job has completed and doesnot needs to be reschedule. Set jobFinished false so that it can rescheduled on a change of network
                    jobFinished(parameters, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setPersisted(boolean)` method.